# intellij 11.1.4 ultimate grails setup

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I have intellij 11.1.4 ultimate and I'm  trying to create a Grails project. I can't select a Grails SDK when creating a project. I have looked around and can't find a clear solution on how to set this up step by step.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean you can't select a Grails SDK?

Comment: What OS do you use? What path do you specify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [download Grails](http://grails.org/Download) version you want to use
2. extract it somewhere on disk
3. start IntelliJ IDEA
4. *File / Settings / Plugins*, check if *Grails* plugin is installed
5. *File / New Project / Create project from scratch* , click *Next*
6. fill out the form and make sure to select *Select type: Grails Module*, click *Next*
7. select Grails version in *Use library*

   1. **if there is no library in combobox**
   2. click on button *Create...*
   3. select folder where you extracted Grails SDK (point 1 and 2)
8. click *Finish*

If this will not help you, there is JetBrains is having [superior support](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=IDEA), I always got answer to my questions.